# Get value from Json list then validate the value appear in list

Tags: json, robotframework

I want to check the value `"train-again-v1-16k"` appears in any of the `"model_name"`.

I am able to get the response, then I want to make sure the list contains value by using  `Dictionary Should Contain Value`.

Test case failed:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Please advise what is the correct syntax to check the value in a list.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Browser
Library  String
Library  RequestsLibrary
Library  Collections
Library  RPA.JSON

*** Test Cases ***
001-Models-Deploy
    Create Session   mysession   ${SRS-API-Host}
    ${response}=    GET    ${SRS-API-Host}/models_list
    ${models}=    Get values from JSON    ${response.json()}    $..model_name    
    Log To Console     models is${models}
    Dictionary Should Contain Value     ${models}     'train-again-v1-16k'
```

GET Response:

```
{
    "message": "",
    "status": "ok",
    "valid_model_list": [
        {
            "corpus_list": [
                "test1"
            ],
            "display_name": "16000samplerate-60train-40test-v1-16k",
            "language": "NO INFO",
            "lexicon": "001_Lex_one_using_001_wav_stm_only",
            "model_name": "16000samplerate-60train-40test-v1-16k",
            "status": true,
            "train_duration": "1.0 Hrs"
        },
        {
            "corpus_list": [
                "Corpus3397"
            ],
            "display_name": "train-again-v1-16k",
            "language": "NO INFO",
            "lexicon": "NTU",
            "model_name": "train-again-v1-16k",
            "status": true,
            "train_duration": "1.33 Hrs"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get values from JSON` returns a list with all matching values, while `Dictionary Should Contain Value` works with and expects, well, a dictionary object.

Just change the keyword for asserting a value is present with something that works with lists - [`List Should Contain Value`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#List%20Should%20Contain%20Value), or just `Should Contain`:

```
List Should Contain Value     ${models}     train-again-v1-16k
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the `Should Contain`, the list obtained from `Get values from JSON` , the specific value is asserted.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Browser
Library  String
Library  RequestsLibrary
Library  Collections
Library  RPA.JSON
Resource            ../Resources/BrowserFunctions.robot
Suite Setup         Start New Browser
Suite Teardown      Close Browser



*** Test Cases ***
001-Models-Deploy
   #Verify model appear at SRS API Model List
    Create Session   mysession   ${SRS-API-Host}
    ${response}=    GET    ${SRS-API-Host}/models_list
    ${models}=    Get values from JSON    ${response.json()}    $..model_name

    Log To Console     models is${models}

    Should Contain    ${models}    sourcemodel8k8020-v1-8k
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).